# Unable to get the referrer information

Tags: google-analytics, gtag.js

I am very new in Google Analytics. I am stuck in very basic problem. Actually I have a page **abc.com/ab.html** . In this page there is a link of **xyz.com/getref.html**. on **getref.html** i have paste following tracking code.

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-FAKEID123"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-FAKEID123');
</script>
```

After clicking on the link on **abc.com/ab.html** it redirect me on **xyz.com/getref.html** . But I am not able to get the referrer information in **Acquistion/All Trafic/Referrals** section. It showing nothing in this section. Please Help me what could be the issue.

Comment: Is abc.com in HTTPS and the xyz.com link using HTTP instead of HTTPS ?

Comment: no both are running on HTTPS

Comment: Thanks, but what about the xyz.com LINK ? Is it HTTP or HTTPS ?

Comment: xyz.xom link is on HTTPS

Comment: What is the value of document.referrer on the landing page on xyz.com/getref.html ? (open console)
Does the link opens in a new window ?